# Static method for XMLLoader class... how to return XML data after Event.COMPLETE function?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, events, return-value, static-methods

I am attempting to build a generic XMLLoader class with a static `LOAD` method, with the intent to use it as follows...

```
private var _data:XML = XMLLoader.LOAD("path/to/xml_file.xml");
```

Then I could use it in any client and go-to-town with e4x.

The general problem I am having is with the URLLoader's `COMPLETE` event, which necessarily calls a different function to set the XML data.
This is preventing me from being able to return the XML from the `LOAD` method, since the data is being set *outside* that function. Obviously I need to wait for the `COMPLETE` event in order to make sure the data is available.

I though, perhaps, I could create and return a `_waitForData` function, which recursively calls itself until the _data is set, then returns the data. But it seems redundant (since `Event.COMPLETE` is doing that anyway), and the way I tried it generates a stack overflow error.

Heres what I tried:

```
public class XMLLoader {

    private static var _url:String = "";
    private static var _data:XML = null;

    public static function LOAD(url:String):XML {

        _url = url;
        var _xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _setData);
            _xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(_url));

        return _waitForData();
    }

    static function _setData(e:Event):void {
        XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        _data = new XML(e.target.data);
    }

    static function _waitForData():XML {

        if( _data == null ) {
             _waitForData();
        }

        return _data;
    }

    public function LoadXML() {}

}
```

I pretty new to the concept of recursive functions, so I have a feeling I implemented my _waitForData function incorrectly (if its even a good idea at all).

I would appreciate any pointers on using static methods in this way, and whether what I am trying to do is possible...seems like a good idea I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to go the all static route. It's a mess, complicates things without need, is hard to mantain and what if you want to load two xmls at the same time? (hint: you can't).

You are better off creating a regular class that does what you want (load an xml and dispatch an event or call a function with the results). Then, you may add a *simpler* interface for your calling code; if that's a static function to be used as a one-liner, so be it. This function could be seen as a kind of factory that initiates creates an instance of the class and also initiates the load operation sets the result callback, all in one step (from the caller perspective)

I'm thinking something along these lines (just wrote it and compiles fine; haven't tested it thoroughly, but should be enough to give the idea).

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public class XMLLoader extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var _loader:URLLoader;
        private var _data:XML;
        private var _callback:Function;

        private static var _map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

        public function XMLLoader(callback:Function = null)
        {
            _data = null;
            _callback = callback;
            _loader = new URLLoader();
            _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,handleError);
            _loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,handleError);
            _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handleComplete);
        }

        public function load(request:URLRequest):void {
            _loader.load(request);  
        }

        private function dispatchError():void {
            cleanUp();  
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
            if(_callback is Function) {
                _callback(null);
            }
        }

        private function dispatchSuccess():void {
            cleanUp();  
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
            if(_callback is Function) {
                _callback(_data);
            }
        }

        private function handleError(e:Event):void {
            dispatchError();
        }

        private function handleComplete(e:Event):void {
            var success:Boolean = false;
            try {
                _data = new XML(e.target.data);
                success = true;
            } catch(err:TypeError) {
                success = false;
            } finally {
                if(success) {
                    dispatchSuccess();
                } else {
                    dispatchError();
                }
            }
        }

        public function get data():XML {
            return _data;
        }

        private function cleanUp():void {
            if(_loader) {
                _loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,handleError);
                _loader.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,handleError);
                _loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handleComplete);
            }
            if(_map[this]) {
                delete _map[this];
            }
        }

        public static function loadXml(url:String,callback:Function):XMLLoader {
            var loader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader(callback);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
            //  pin down the instance just to be safe; I've seen loaders being collected...
            _map[loader] = true;
            return loader;
        }

    }
}
```

Use:

```
    private function handleResult(data:XML):void {
        if(data) {
            trace(data);
        } else {
            trace("failed");
        }
    }


    private function test():void {
        XMLLoader.loadXml("your.xml",handleResult);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could switch to use the instance methods, if you need more flexibility:

```
    private function test():void {
        var loader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader(handleResult);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("your.xml"));        
    }
```

This sample implementation could be used with callback or events. For simplicity I'm just defining one callback function; you could tell if the loading operation succeded by checking the data you receive; null means it failed. Also, I'm dispatching an Event.COMPLETE event to signal the loader finished loading (even if it failed); again, you could know if it failed or succeded by checking the data property. You could use custom events if you want and/or define a fault callback, but I think you want a simpler as possible interface, so I think this should be enough.

Comment: This is an EXTREMELY instructive example, well beyond the response I hoped for. I will study your comments and sample code thoroughly and suggest others do as well.
Thanks!

Comment: @Logic Artist. No problem, I'm glad you find my anwser useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking too much of the system, flash wasn't designed for this. You can't (or shouldn't) hang the whole system just in order to wait for one result. Writing in flex/flash necessitates using completion handlers because in some cases, like this, there's just no way around it. If you did things this way, the frames would never move forwards, and everything in the program would come to a screeching halt until the thing returned, making a very unhappy user experience that would feel like "hanging" or "crashing".

On the technical side, if you absolutely, positively insisted on doing this, then you would (1) have to find a way to put a delay in that if-null loop, and (2) change it to a `while( _data != null ){ /* wait a while */ }` but I **really** don't recommend going down that path. More specifically, you need to be careful when calling a function inside itself. In your case, `_waitForData` is asking `_waitForData` to ask `_waitForData` to ask `_waitForData` to... etc, until it hits an arbitrary limit and halts. It's called [infinite recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion).

Solution: You need to structure your program so that it stops doing what its doing when it needs to load something, and picks up doing what it needs to when a completion handler gets called.

Update:

Solution 2: Write a class that does handles all the XML loading you need. You can have it pre-populate things at the beginning of the program if you know what might be asked-for. Then, as you need more of them, ask the class for more. Then, if it already has it loaded, it can just hand it back immediately. If it doesn't have it, it'll return `null`, fetch it in the background and call a handler when it's done. That way, the code calling it can at least try to do things with the XML immediately, but in the end, it will always have to handle the case for when it's not loaded.

Comment: Fair enough...I figured the recursive loop was a bad idea. However the primary problem is not really that the loop halts the program (thats just a side-effect of a bad solution)...its that I need a way to return data from the static function that uses an event handler. Thanks though.

Comment: return data to whom? must the function be static?

Comment: Return data to the context in which it is called. The idea is to pass a url to the method (as demonstrated above), without having to instantiate the class. Think of, say, flash's Math class, just pass in a value to one of its static methods and it returns the answer. Sure it doesn't have to be static, but that way I can create a simple, reusable, one-line method.

Comment: why the aversion to creating a class? will you be doing this really frequently, like many times per second? if not, i wouldn't worry about the overhead. you can create and destroy a million XMLLoader's in the time it takes for one of them to return data. :-)